# using --dport on iptable rules , leading me "No chain/target/match by that name."

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm using qemu on ububntu environment to launch linux based OS as a guest.

I'm giving kernel file as bzimage and ext4 files as main file while launching guest os from qemu.

$ sudo qemu-system-i386 -enable-kvm -kernel bzImage-linux-yocto-qemux86.bin ........ -drive file=apollo-image-qemux86.ext4,if=virtio ....

Once the guest launched, I tried to use firewalls to filterout using the iptables rules.

My plan is to block anyport, but one port (eg: http, ftp, ssh) only.

I gave like this  (by typing , not copy pasted)

### $ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP

but I don't understand the output:

### result:

### iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

where as in host system, the same command is working fine to just block that port.

Can anyone help me to getout of this problem? And explain to me what is actually the problem?

Comment: What's the output of "sudo iptables -L" ?

Comment: @DurdenP , nothing rule got applied there.. 
chain of empty

Comment: This is the output of the command "sudo iptables -L"? I'd like to know if exist the chain INPUT

Comment: INPUT chain is there...

Here is the result for "iptable -L"


--------------------------------------------------------
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
--------------------------------------------------

Comment: @DurdenP , INPUT chain is there in the list , here i'm giving only INPUT chain from "iptable -L"

**
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

**